# Is a hornetq cluster designed to cope with loosing 1 or more nodes?

Tags: cluster-computing, high-availability, hornetq

I know there's HornetQ HA with Master/Backup setups. But I would like to run HornetQ in a non-master setup and handle duplicate messages myself.

The cluster setup looks perfect for this, but nowhere I see a hint to its ability to service such these requirements. What happens to clients of a failed node? Do they connect to other servers?
Will a  rebooted/repaired node be able to rejoin the cluster and continue distribution of its persistent messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failover on clients require a backup node at the moment. you would have to reconnect manually in case of a failure to get into other nodes.

Example: get the connection factory and connect there.